# Disable links in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, hyperlink

I am loading some content from the web into a `UIWebView`, but I'd like all links to be disabled in the `UIWebView`. Is this possible? I could parse the text, but I'm looking for something easier.

Comment: You can do this by running a javascript snippet in your webview, `-[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptString:].`

Comment: do you know this script ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can give the `UIWebView` a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) and implement the [`-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951-CH3-SW6) delegate method to `return NO;` (except on the initial load).

That will prevent the user from viewing anything but that single page.

To provide an example requested in the comments...  Start with `allowLoad=YES` and then:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    return allowLoad;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
    allowLoad = NO;
}
```

Comment: How to avoid this for inital load only?

Comment: @Praveen I'd start by returning a variable that's initially `YES` but is set to `NO` in `-webViewDidFinishLoad:`.

Comment: No, i'm not getting, `webViewDidFinishLoad` is not a boolean method. Then, how can we return there?

Comment: @Praveen I'm saying that you use the fact that `-webViewDidFinishLoad` is called as an indication that the first load has finished.  Once that method is invoked, you know that you can then return `NO` from the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:...` method in the future.

Comment: Okay. Any examples related to this?

Comment: Set **allowLoad = YES;** before loading your INITIAL page. Once initial page finished loading (in webViewDidFinishLoad), set "allowLoad = NO;". So that, no further pages will be loaded.

Answer (score 11):

Tested in Swift 4.0: This approach doesn't involve having an extra variable to test if this is the initial load or not. Simply check the type of request (in this case, LinkClicked) and return false in that case. Otherwise simply return true!

(Of course make sure you set the `webView.delegate`)

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == .linkClicked {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can disable data detect from your webview.

```
[webView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeNone];
```

Comment: RainCast did you mean open youtube app from webview or just youtube web page ?

Answer (score 1):

For swift 3:

Try removing the types you don't want to show as link from `webView.dataDetectorTypes`

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes.remove(UIDataDetectorTypes.all)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer instead of just posting one (unformatted) line of code.

Comment: @FabianSchöner I edited to add some explanation and added the formatting. The solution works, voting it down would make people think the solution is wrong and not trying this solution.

Comment: i didnt downvote, i just added the comment. Thanks for making things clear by editing your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Another answer for Swift 3.0 :
Just give zero for don't detect any type link of yourWebView initial code

```
yourWebView.dataDetectorTypes =  UIDataDetectorTypes(rawValue: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer that works in Swift 2.0:

```
yourWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.None
```

Just implement it in the view controller where you are defining and using your web view and it will work flawlessly.

Comment: @RainCast did you find a solution for YouTube (to prevent go on site and display only a video)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and for some cases just using the webViewDidFinishLoad was not enough, so I used the webViewDidStartLoad to cover all cases:

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    startedLoading = true
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    alreadyOpen = true
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if startedLoading && alreadyOpen {
        // do something
        return false
    }else if startedLoading && !alreadyOpen{
        return false
    }else if !startedLoading {
        return true
    }
    return true
}
```

In some cases when the html was loaded but some resources, like images and some heavy assets inside the DOM were not the didFinishLoad method was not fired and the user could navigate in this "short" interval.