# How to disable dynamic content in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I used techniques in

[Disable links in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098797/disable-links-in-uiwebview)

to disable links in a wikipedia mobile view page by returning false to webView function. It works well for links.

However, I found the dynamic content as mobile menu, search bar, login etc can still be invoked. e.g

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House

I am not familiar with dynamic web design. What kind of techniques are in those contents?

How can I disable them in UIWebView?